# Adding Elementor Background Image conflicts with CSS Styling

Tags: wordpress, elementor, migrating

I migrated a website from a subdomain to the final domain and I had bunch of problems regard CSS and images.

If I use standard background image the CSS on website doesn't works, only with background presentation image it works properly.

I  tried everything on the internet:

- regenerating CSS
- disabled experiments in elementor
- clear cache  and used incognito
- upgrade or downgrade Elementor version
- tried php 7.2, 7.4 and 8.0

The only problem that solved my problem was changing the background image from single image to presentation.

If i use standard background image it appreas gray and doesnt appear at all on the website, beside that, the CSS works only if I use presentation mode on background images.

Anyone knows any fix for this?

I used background image here : [background image used here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2EFs.png)
I used presentation image here: [presentation image used here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Apbb.png)